# Git config killing my build when trying to clone. How to debug?

Tags: git, clone, git-config

I'm trying to run a script to build a repo. First I need to pull it down, then build it.
When the script runs, it dies on the git clone command with:

```
fatal: bad config line 10 in file .git/config
```

The .git/config file is:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<my-correct-handle>@bitbucket.org/<myrepo>/scrabble.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "release/2.1.1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/release/2.1.1
```

We need to pull down the branch named "release/2.1.1" from the repo to build it.

FYI we have valid hashes in .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD and .git/refs/remotes/branches/release/2.1.1

Finally the git command is:

```
git clone https://<my correct handle>@bitbucket.org/<my project>/scrabble.git --branch release/2.1.1 .
```

Comment: Are you trying to clone within a working directory of another repo?  You can't do that, and it makes no sense to do so.  Prior to doing a `git clone` there should be *NO* .git directory in the current directory or any parent.

Comment: @Chris thank you! No, it's a brand new directory. But I discovered that this line before it: 'apt -y install wget unzip zip curl git build-essential apt-utils' creates .git etc in the current directory.